# Android : Images and video path in same cursor without cursorLoader

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show video and images from memory using content resolver but i don't want to use cursorLoader for it.

I am using below code to get uri of file but it only returns images but i want images as well as videos uri.

```
private fun getAllShownPath(activity:Activity):ArrayList<String> {
        val uri:Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        var cursor:Cursor?= null
        val columnIndexData:Int
        val columnIndexFolderName:Int
        val listOfAllImages = ArrayList<String>()
        var absolutePathOfImage:String? = null
        val projection = arrayOf<String>(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
        cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
        columnIndexData = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
        columnIndexFolderName = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(columnIndexData)
            listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage)
        }
        return listOfAllImages

    }
```

What i am doing wrong here ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, 
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE
    };

// This will Return only video and image metadata.

String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE 
         + " OR "
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
    this,
    queryUri,
    projection,
    selection,
    null, // Selection args (none).
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC" // Sort order.
  );
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it without CursorLoader ?